# expose documents from iOS App Group Container in Files app

Tags: ios, swift, containers, ios-app-group, files-app

My iOS app and its extension successfully share files locally through an app-group container. The app also exposes files in the Documents folder of its app container to the Files app, after setting `UISupportsDocumentBrowser` in the app's info.plist.

How can I **expose files stored in the app-group's container to the Files app?**

The extension (a widget) generates files in the app-group container and shares them with the app this way. Currently the app copies changed files from the app-group container to the app container's Documents folder to expose them to the Files app. This entails a delay, as the app can copy only when it is running, in the fore- or background.

Comment: I guess it's not possible right?

Comment: @aehlke I still don't know how.